# Tracking Users login & logout details using software for VM (Virtual Machine -Windows OS)

Tags: virtual-machine

I have hosted a VM (Virtual Machine - Windows OS) on a server. Anyone can login into this VM if he/she has credential and we have common credential. **All the users login with same username (administrator) and same password.**

**Sometimes we get some unwanted activity so I want to track the machine from where it has been logged in and logged out.**

Sorry if it an easy question or out of scope but I am not an infra person so I do not have much idea about it.

Can anyone suggest me some software using which I can track the activity.